# Printing arguments passed through the command line

Tags: c++

I tried to print the arguments passed through the command line as follows:

```
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::cout << argv[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << argv[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << argv[2] << std::endl;
}
```

but failed. The output was:

```
./a.out
first
second
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7743f81c97249fb6)**

It wasn't what I expected. I expected something like that:

```
first
second
__some_garbage_data__
```

Is the binary name always treated as an argument with the index `0`?

Comment: _"Is the binary name always treated as an argument with the index 0?"_ Yes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But what was the reason for that? I don't understand where it could be useful.

Comment: Your program file can have different names (e.g. symbolic links), and change behavior accordingly. See e.g. how `g(un)zip` works like this.

Comment: I believe that in linux you can also have a file and several links to it (not actual files). I suppose that you might be interested in which link has made the call to the program for specific behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is expected behavior. From [basic.start.main], emphasis mine:

> If `argc` is nonzero these arguments
>   shall be supplied in `argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]` as pointers to the initial characters of null-terminated
>   multibyte strings (ntmbs s) (17.5.2.1.4.2) and `argv[0]` **shall be the pointer to the initial character of a
>   ntmbs that represents the name used to invoke the program or ""**. The value of `argc` shall be non-negative.
>   The value of `argv[argc]` shall be `0`.

Comment: All right, now that's clear. But what that was introduced for? Couldn't you get an example where it would be really useful?

Comment: @DmitryBundin Sometimes it's handy to know how your program called. Certainly at least helps with debugging information. Maybe you need the path or any number of other things.

Answer (score 1):

In most languages the first argument is the program itself. In your case, argv[0] will always print ./a.out

Answer (score 0):

arg[0] stores name of program called and after that argv stores the arguments that were passed in the command line.

$./a.out hello hi

```
 0     1   2
```

So

```
 argv[0]=a.out
 argv[1]=hello
 argv[2]=hi
```

Answer (score 0):

`argv[0]` not only shows the name of file but also shows you the path, exmaple if you run the program without having changed the directory to the programs directory an output like below would show up(windows):

`C:\Users\username\desktop\program.exe`.

On linux, like your example outputs `./a.out` where `./` represents current directory.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you call your program from the command line, its 0th argument is going to be the name of the file/command itself. So basically, the arguments you have passed are from the first member of the array onwards.

If you include

```
cout << argv[3]
```

you will get what you are expecting.

Comment: _"you will get what you are expecting"_ Nope, that's plain wrong! You can't rely on _getting garbage value_. It's actually undefined behavior, anything can happen.

Comment: What's undefined about getting a piece of text and outputting it to a stream? Just because he said garbage value, that doesn't mean it's actually garbage...

Comment: Dereferencing `nullptr` is UB, and `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to hold a `nullptr`. So what?

Comment: argc is going to be 4 in this case, why would you call argv[argc]? I'm talking about argv[argc-1]

Comment: _"I'm talking about `argv[argc-1]`"_ Sorry, I meant the same. Just to remind you `./a.out first second` gives you `argc == 4`, where `argv[3] == nullptr` is `true`.